# CLLocationSpeed Issue

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get my code to return the velocity of the device in miles per hour with the following:

```
double speed = newLocation.speed;
NSString *speedyspeed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (speed*2.2369)];
yourSpeed.text = speedyspeed;
```

the "speed*2.2369" is supposed to correct for the fact that the speed is returned in meters/second rather than miles/hour like I want.  Regardless, I'm getting values of, like, -173498723 instead of normal values.  I'm clearly doing something wrong.  The speed value string is then assigned to output to my UILabel called "yourSpeed".

Any suggestions?

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use %f instead of %d as you are using a double, and not an integer.

Source: [String Programming Guide for Cocoa - String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)